# Wall cladding for shower?

Tags: bathroom, walls, shower, bathtub

We have a second bathroom with a bathtub. There is a shower hose and a shower holder as well, so in theory we could use the bathtub also as a shower, but there is no protection on the walls around the tub, so I suppose this would destroy them. I wonder what can be done here. I suppose one could get tiles on the wall, but that would be very expensive and probably annoying to install. Another solution I read about would be waterproof wall cladding. What needs to be done to install this? Does the wall behind it need to be treated with some waterproof colour or something? Can the installation of cladding be done by myself? I don't really have any tools and to be honest I don't really like DIY and am extremely bad at it, so would prefer someone professional to do it. I just contacted some bathroom design firm and they quoted me £3500 for the material and work, which sounds a bit excessive. Would this be the expected price for something like this or are they trying to take advantage of me? If I don't go for this, would a normal handyman be the appropriate person to do this, provided I purchase the material myself?
I am attaching a photo for clarification. Any comments or suggestions on what to do are very welcome- as you see I'm not very knowledgeable in this ...
[image]

Comment: Questions of pricing are explicitly off topic. Please [edit] your question to remove that or it risks being closed. To find out if this is a reasonable price, contact several contractors in your area and ask them all for quotes for the work you desire - it's the only way to find out what's appropriate in your area. Additionally, you've asked about a dozen questions here. As a long-time SE member, you should know that it's "one question per question" here.

Answer (score 4):

At the easy low-cost end, you could install a clawfoot (*i.e.* freestanding) tub shower curtain rod that goes all the way around the tub, and a curtain to match. They work in the middle of a room, they'll work in an alcove too.